# json_encode doesn't display all array values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP script where it fetches all records from a table and encodes it to JSON. The table has a total of **246 records**. `echo count();` returns 246 as well.

The problem is, whenever I use `json_encode`, it doesn't display the values from the array at all, all I see is a blank page. But if I reduce the number of records to 13 instead of 246, it works and it displays the encoded JSON result. I have also tried to increase the `memory_limit` at my php.ini file to 4095M, but no avail.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cities");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $response["cities"] = array();
     $city = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $city[] = $row;
          array_push($response["cities"], $city);
     }

     $response["success"] = 1;
     echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below and you'll get to know what is happening exactly:

```
$json = json_encode($response);

if ($json)
    echo $json;
else
    echo json_last_error_msg();
```

> [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) - Returns the error string of the last json_encode() or json_decode() call

Comment: Thank you! It returns "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded", gave me an idea about the problem :)

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Array "city" is expanding for each call and you are pushing the complete array on each iteration in loop .

Try :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          array_push($response["cities"], $row);
     }
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$response` array push `$row` into `$cities` array. After pushing all city set the city and response in `json_encode();` function like this `echo json_encode(array("cities"=>$cities, "success"=>1));`

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $cities = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          array_push($cities, $row);
     }

     echo json_encode(array("cities"=>$cities, "success"=>1));
}
```